# Webpack 5 and webpack-dev-server generate differently named chunks with same config

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, code-splitting

### Problem:

I use the same code splitting webpack config for production and development but webpack / webpack-dev-server are generating different chunks, especially differently named chunks. Due to these different names I can't include the chunks by name in the CMS templates.

### Goal:

Getting equally named artifacts in production and dev mode to include in the website / CMS template by name as it was while using webpack 4. Code splitting should remain to outsource common used modules in separate chunks.

### Current config and results:

Versions used: webpack-dev-server@3.10.3, webpack@5.0.0-beta.13

I'm generating assets for a Content Management driven website using webpack and webpack-dev-server. The JS bundles are included by name in the footer template of the CMS as defererred scripts. There is currently no dynamic loading of modules by webpack during runtime (yes, that might be desirable...).

This is my current config (assumed relevant parts):

*webpack.config.base* (common settings merged in dev/prod settings):

```
entry: {
    handlers: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/resources/js/handlers-bundle.js'),
    videoplayer: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/resources/js/handlers-video.js'),
    styles: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/resources/scss/styles.scss'),
},
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    // chunkFilename: '[name].js',
    path: config.output,
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
    }),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
],
optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'size',
    chunkIds: 'size',
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        maxInitialRequests: Infinity,
        minSize: 0,
        // name: false,
    },
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
    minimizer: [
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
            },
        }),
    ],
},
```

*webpack.config.dev* (started via "webpack-dev-server --hotOnly --config ./webpack.config.dev.js")

```
mode: 'development',
devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',
devServer: {
    port: config.port,
    // contentBase: config.output,
    inline: true,
    watchOptions: {
        poll: 1000,
        ignored: /node_modules/,
    },
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    compress: true,
},
plugins: [
    new HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
],
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            cache: false,
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
    ],
},
```

*webpack.config.prod* (started via "webpack --config ./webpack.config.prod.js"):

```
mode: 'production',
stats: {
    assets: true,
    chunks: true,
    entrypoints: true,
    modules: true,
    warnings: false,
},
plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
],
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
            cache: false,
        }),
    ],
},
performance: {
    hints: false,
},
```

With webpack 4 I got these named artifacts in dev and prod build:

- vendors~videoplayer.js
- videoplayer.js
- vendors~handlers.js
- vendors~handlers~videoplayer.js
- handlers~videoplayer.js
- handlers.js

With my current webpack 5 setup I get these artifatcs:

prod build:

> Entrypoint handlers [big] = runtime.js 1.js 4.js 2.js handlers.css
>   handlers.js
>
> Entrypoint videoplayer [big] = runtime.js 1.js 3.js 2.js
>   videoplayer.js
>
> Entrypoint styles [big] = runtime.js 8.css styles.css styles.js

dev build / dev-server:

> Entrypoint handlers = runtime.js 1.js **3.js 7.js** 2.js 4.js handlers.css
>   handlers.js
>
> Entrypoint videoplayer = runtime.js 1.js 3.js **5.js** 2.js **4.js**
>   videoplayer.js
>
> Entrypoint styles = runtime.js 1.js 10.css 2.js styles.css styles.js

### What I tried already:

- changing splitchunks / chunks to "initial" - no difference
- experimenting with moduleIds and chunkIds i.e. with "named" or "deterministic" or completely omitting these settings, but still different chunk names and count
- experimenting with maxInitialRequests: Reducing to 3 gave the same amount of chunks in dev and prod but still different chunk names
- splitchunks / name: false - no difference

I assume webpack-dev-server is introducing its own needed modules into the bundles and maybe this leads to more chunks with my configuration. But I have no further idea how to force same number and names of the generated chunks.

Does anyone have an idea what the reason might be or what to change to enforce the same behavior as it was with webpack 4?

Comment: Have you tried setting `optimization.splitChunks.name` to some string, e.g. `vendors`?